# What method would you recommend to make Operating System API calls in a cross-platform library you are building?

Tags: c++, c

Let me explain further .. 
Is it advisable to use , something like :

```c
#ifdef _WIN32
void someFunction()
{
   // windows version  of the function which makes Windows API Calls
}
#elif defined(__linux__)
void someFunction()
{
   // linux version of the function which makes POSIX calls 
}
#endif
```

OR  create separate source code files for each operating systems, and then use conditional codes in makefiles or any build tools to compile the source code based on the operating system ???

Comment: There's no clear right answer that people have settled on. Both of the approaches you mention are commonly used. Feel free to use your judgment and decide for yourself.

Comment: What are the advantages and disadvantages of either approach? I've seen projects that used both variants. Depending on the particular spot, they made a decision for either variant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, "best" is at some level opinion-based and might get this question closed. However, my view is that you should work from a standpoint that there is one set of **P**ortable **O**perating **S**ystem **I**nterfaces (+**X**), and that these are what you code to. Then, for systems that lack some or all of the portable interfaces, you can provide drop-in replacement implementations built on top of whatever OS-specific interfaces the particular oddball operating system wants you to use.

This allows you to keep complex conditionals and OS-specific logic out of your actual program logic, and isolate it all as platform-support shims. Some people prefer to do this by *building their own* portability layer (APR, NSPR, etc.) and treating POSIX just as one of the backends for it. I strongly recommend against doing this, since:

1. It imposes significant levels of overhead on systems that already have a portable interface.
2. It makes your code hard to read by people who know the standard interfaces but who aren't familar with your own portability layer.
3. It makes your code hard to reuse in projects where your portability layer isn't a good fit.
4. It's a huge rabbit hole of yak-shaving that will bog you down and take all your time away from whatever you actually wanted to code.

Comment: This is a good answer, although I technically disagree with it. In any case, it offers yet another alternative approach: Just don't code your own OS-specific abstractions but use an existing one, like e.g. the mentioned Apache Portable Runtime (APR).

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: Indeed that's an option, but actually reading the source to those was my motivation for bullet point 1. I once hit a problem with svn's code paths to print messages, and found it going through like 4 layers of "portable runtime" stuff to do what was the equivalent of a single portable `printf` call. (And ultimately the problem was because whatever it was doing back then in one of these layers was *not actually portable*.)